# How query all results in a Relational Table?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, foreign-key-relationship

In a QUERY I've SELECT a specific product data from Book Table. Like title, author, year, etc. I wanna get all it's authors, but it's **only showing the** **first one**.

Product Table:

```
produto
   idproduto
   sku
   titulo
   others not important
```

Author Table:

```
autor
   id_autor
   nome_autor
```

Relational Table:

```
    autorxprod
        idautoria
        idprod (FK)
        idautor (FK)
```

How show all authors that are related to the Book1??
Should I make another QUERY inside the main QUERY??

---

EDITED WITH CODE. I'VE COMMENTED A BIT CAUSE IT'S IN PORTUGUESE

```
$produto = $_GET['sku']; 
$idproduto = $_GET['idprod'];

$query = "SELECT 

p.titulo AS titulo, p.imgprod AS imgprod, p.marca AS idmarca, p.sku AS sku,
p.prodcateg AS prodcateg, p.ano AS ano, p.titeng AS titeng,
p.codbarra AS codbarra, p.desc AS descricao, // product infos

c.idcategoria AS idcategoria, c.nomecateg AS nomecateg, // category infos
m.nome_marca AS nome_marca, // brand info

a.nome_autor AS nome_autor, // author info
a.id_autor AS idautor   // author id

FROM (produto p, autor a)

   LEFT JOIN categoria c // category join
   ON p.prodcateg = c.idcategoria

   LEFT JOIN marcas m // brand join
   ON p.marca = m.id_marca  

   LEFT JOIN autorxprod axp // relational table
   ON p.idproduto = axp.idprod
   AND a.id_autor = axp.idautor


   WHERE p.sku LIKE '$produto'";

   $result = $conn ->query ($query);


if (!$result) die ($conn->error);

$rows = $result->num_rows;  

    for ($j = 0; $j <$rows; ++$j)
    {
        $result -> data_seek($j);
        $row = $result->fetch_array (MYSQLI_ASSOC);?>

 -----------

 <?php echo $row['nome_autor']?>
```

Comment: Show us what you've tried so far.

Comment: what have you written? can i see the query?

Comment: How did you structure your tables?  The relationship between book and Author is a Many-to-Many relationship (a Book can have 1 or more authors and an author can Author more than one book).  You should have a book table, author table and a BookAuthor Table.

Comment: Yes, I have 3 tables, cause it's many-to-many. But I just get the first result from BookAuthor Table, and not all the Authors that writed the book.

Comment: Could you post your three tables in detail? It's easier to help that way

Comment: Posted my tables details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for all patient with me, as I'm learning I was really lost.
Here is the completed result for what I need, and it's working as expected.
Much more simple than before.

This code gets all authors from related product and shows as Author 1, Author 2, Author 3...

```
"SELECT     
            ....get stuff...

            a.id_autor AS idautor,
            GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT a.nome_autor ORDER BY a.nome_autor SEPARATOR ', ') AS autor_list


        FROM 

        produto p

        LEFT JOIN categoria c
        ON p.prodcateg = c.idcategoria  

        LEFT JOIN marcas m
        ON p.marca = m.id_marca     

        LEFT OUTER JOIN (autor a, autorxprod axp)
        ON axp.idautor = a.id_autor AND
        axp.idprod = '$produto'


        WHERE
        p.sku = '$produto'
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe it is wrong but your sql is a little strange in mixing the join styles.  Can I suggest this:

```
SELECT 
  p.titulo AS titulo, p.imgprod AS imgprod, p.marca AS idmarca, p.sku AS sku,
  p.prodcateg AS prodcateg, p.ano AS ano, p.titeng AS titeng,
  p.codbarra AS codbarra, p.desc AS descricao, // product infos

  c.idcategoria AS idcategoria, c.nomecateg AS nomecateg, // category infos
  m.nome_marca AS nome_marca, // brand info

  a.nome_autor AS nome_autor, // author info
  a.id_autor AS idautor   // author id

FROM produto p
LEFT JOIN categoria c  ON p.prodcateg = c.idcategoria
LEFT JOIN marcas m  ON p.marca = m.id_marca  
LEFT JOIN autorxprod axp ON p.idproduto = axp.idprod
JOIN autor a ON a.id_autor = axp.idautor
-- above is what your code did, you could also use a left join like this and you might have null authors
-- LEFT JOIN autor a ON a.id_autor = axp.idautor
WHERE p.sku LIKE '$produto'
```

Comment: Hi Hogan, thanks for your help. I've tried with both. JOIN shows nothing (neither product title), LEFT JOIN shows product title but doesn't shows any author at all. :/

Comment: @bibiana sounds like the book is not in the autorxprod table.

Comment: Hogan, the book id and author id is in autorxprod table.

Comment: yes I know that is what you said.  If you are getting the results you described then the data is not in the table... dump the table for the rows you expect to be there and see.

Comment: I'm sure there is data on that table :)

Comment: Ok. But is it the correct data as you describe in your data model... I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

I may be mistaken but it seem to me that you would want to run two separate queries. One query to get the Book that matches the search and a second query to get all the authors of the book.  Because the relation table is a many to one you will end up with a result set that has the same book listed multiple times, one for each author, if you try to join the tables.  Is that what you want?

If I am mistaken and you do want multiple records for each book, here is a simplified version of the join query you would need.

```
SELECT 
 p.titulo AS titulo
 a.nome_autor
FROM 
 author a,
 produto p
 LEFT JOIN autorxprod axp
 ON  axp.idprod =p.idproduto 
WHERE 
 p.sku LIKE '$produto'
 AND  axp.idautor = a.id_autor
```

Comment: Hi rmp. Maybe I need 2 queries, I'm not shure. First I get the book by GET url, second I want to get all authors for this book. I think relational is many-to-many, cause an author could write many books, and a book could have many authors. I've tried your solution but it shows nothing. I've removed the AND on WHERE. Now it shows the product twice, but I want to show it just once with both authors.

Comment: If you want to use only one query you could try using a `GROUP_CONCAT()` on your authors. This will not be as flexible for output but it will allow you to return one record for each book and the authors as a concat. list. Also not that by default `GROUP_CONCAT` has a 1024 byte limit so if your table is large you will need to increase this value.

Comment: Actually I'm having a strange result. My query is showing all authors on table, and not just the product ones. How to fix it?? I'm lost.

Comment: your updated query does not have any constraints on the 'autor a' table that you have the `GROUP_CONCAT` on